# Duplicate question on relation between gradient and Jacobian

Tags: discussion, specific-question, exact-duplicates

I am a newbie to multivariable calculus so I am not sure whether I should be bringing this up on Math Meta or not but are these two questions duplicates and if so why they have not been marked ?

[Difference between Jacobian and gradient](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1519367/difference-between-gradient-and-jacobian)

[Gradient Jacobian Row and Column conventions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/336640/gradient-and-jacobian-row-and-column-conventions)

There is another similar question all around the same topic

[Gradient as a row and column vector](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/54355/the-gradient-as-a-row-vs-column-vector)

Comment: It's fine you bring it up. Often things just fall through the cracks, there are hundreds of thousands of questions on the site. If you intend to do this more frequently, you might consider doing to in the dedicated thread: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/24972/the-duplicate-thread

Comment: @quid -if I understood you correctly you want me to post this question as an answer on the duplicate thread. Is that correct ?

Comment: In a way, yes. But certainly you can leave this one as is. Just if you decide to post such things regularly you might use that thread. (Although some might argue it is not the exact purpose of that thread either.)

Comment: @quid - my only interest is in multivariable calculus and vector fields/analysis so if I find duplicate questions I will certainly put them in that thread

Comment: Note that if you are sufficiently convinced something is a duplicate it is often most efficient to just flag it as such: select "flag" below the post, and then pick "duplicate" and input the target. This will put the question in a review queue for other users to double check. If confirmed it will be actually marked as duplicate.